# Cocos2d, swift find when Spritebuilder timeline animation completed via callback

Tags: swift, cocos2d-iphone, callback, spritebuilder

I have a callback setup on timeline in Spritebuilder.
and I have the timeline animation triggered. My goal is to disable touch until animation completes.

```
func triggerTimelineAction(nodeName: CCNode){
    self.userInteractionEnabled = false;
nodeName.animationManager.runAnimationsForSequenceNamed("nodeMainAction")
nodeName.animationManager.setCompletedAnimationCallbackBlock(b: ??? )){
self.userInteractionEnabled = true;
}
}
```

Question: how do I declare callback keyframe and hookup/receive it.

UPD: i was told to pass a function in setCompletedAnim... so i made my code look like:
    func animationCompleted(){
    self.userInteractionEnabled = true;
    }

```
func triggerTimelineAction(nodeName: CCNode){
self.userInteractionEnabled = false;
       nodeName.animationManager.runAnimationsForSequenceNamed("nodeMainAction")
nodeName.animationManager.setCompletedAnimationCallbackBlock(b: @selector(animationCompleted))
```

}

on which I received error "Cannot convert value of type ()->() to expected argument type (AnyObject)->Void

Apparently this is more related to Cocos2d syntaxis. will dig further in that direction

Answer (score 0):

So after a session with codementor I figured out that I was using the setCompletedAnimationCallbackBlock function improperly.

```
In this code
activeNode.animationManager.setCompletedAnimationCallbackBlock(b: ((AnyObject!) -> Void)
```

I was trying to pass arguments as AnyObject
 when in fact this is a block that this function returns.
So this code has worked for me

```
activeNode.animationManager.setCompletedAnimationCallbackBlock { (object: AnyObject!) -> Void in
  print(object)
}
```

where object is just firs time declared name for element that gets returned. The print function showed that object that returns is a CCAnimationManager so it is equal to previous syntax when you had to runAction then assign action.delegate to self and then actually catch callback.
Hope this information helps somebody.